# Why Core Data returns new objects only after app relaunch?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have 2 tables: `Users` and `Plan`, where in`Users` I have `to-many` relation to `Plan` and in `Plan` I have `to-one` relation.

```
Users
@NSManaged public var plans: NSOrderedSet?

Plan
@NSManaged public var user: Users?
```

I'm adding a new record as:

```
user.addToPlans(self.plan)
```

So the problem is, after adding a new plan, it adds it to the table, I can see it in `.sqlite` file BUT when I run this command:

```
print(user.plans.count)
```

I get the old amount of records. To get `oldAmount + 1` count I have to relaunch my app.
What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you update `plans` after adding new plan?

Comment: @trungduc no, I'm not. I'm just going back and fetch all records

Comment: I think that you didn’t fetch all records again after adding new plan

Comment: @trungduc I do. On each `viewWillAppear` I'm trying to get `user.plans` and each time I get old values

Comment: You need to show how you get data, how you update it and everyone can help you